# Keyboard keys not working properly

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Some of the keys in my laptop keyboard are not working properly. Following are the issues:

1. When pressing <kbd>o</kbd>, the keyboard prints 9o. 9o is also getting printed when pressing <kbd>9</kbd>.
2. Also pressing <kbd>0</kbd> (zero) automatically makes the screen as full screen which is the function of <kbd>F11</kbd>.
3. Pressing <kbd>2</kbd> does the function of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> which finds something on the screen.

I have tried [*Some keyboard keys not working properly*](https://superuser.com/questions/147747/some-keyboard-keys-not-working-properly) but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try another keyboard. If the problem goes away then it's the keyboard. Keyboards are prone to becoming damaged and dirty.  I have a bunch of keyboard that need to be taken apart and cleaned, which can be tedious and time consuming, but often the only problem with them is they require a cleaning.