# What does the hotkey Win + Alt Gr + Ctrl do?

Tags: windows-10

I just finished starting up my new laptop (with Windows 10 Home) and two of the keys didn't work. I saw some advice online to try hitting the hotkey in the title. It worked!

My question is: Why? What does it do?

Related: [some keyboard keys not working properly](https://superuser.com/questions/147747/some-keyboard-keys-not-working-properly)

Comment: what do you mean by "two of the keys didn't work"?

Comment: That particular combination does nothing, obviously. One or more of those keys needs to be combined with something else in order to do something. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The left arrow key did not move the cursor (or do anything), and the "6" on the numpad did not do anything (regardless of num lock). After pressing and holding that key combination, they both started working. It definitely did something.

Comment: I added a link to the post where I saw the suggested fix, which has a few upvotes and is on this site.

Comment: By pressing and releasing all the modifier keys, you can sometimes “release” them if software previously missed the key release event.